# Elasticsearch sum aggregration

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

there is documents with category(number), and piece(long) fields. I need some kind of aggregration that group these docs by category and sum all the pieces in it

here how documents looks:

```
{
"category":"1",
"piece":"10.000"
},
{
"category":"2",
"piece":"15.000"
} ,
{
"category":"2",
"piece":"10.000"
},
{
"category":"3",
"piece":"5.000"
} 
...
```

The query result must be like:

```
{
"category":"1",
"total_amount":"10.000"
} 
{
"category":"2",
"total_amount":"25.000"
} 
{
"category":"3",
"total_amount":"5.000"
} 
..
```

any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a terms aggregation on the categories, from the records above I see that you are sending them as strings, so they will be categorical variables. Then, as a metric, pass on the sum.

This is how it might look:

```
        "aggs" : {
            "categories" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : "category"
                },
                "aggs" : {
                    "sum_category" : {
                        "sum": { "field": "piece" } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly true :)